# Connection timed out: connect JAVA and Wampserver

Tags: java, mysql, connection, wampserver

I need help about database connection time error, I'm using wamp server 
I can access PHPMyAdmin throw this link "192.168.1.88/phpmyadmin", it works fine but I get a timeout error in NetBeans, and I tried ping between the PC and it works fine

Here is the stack trace:

```
  java.net.SocketException
  MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

  STACKTRACE:

  java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
  at assurancebensaidv2.jdbcManager.<init>(jdbcManager.java:38)
  at assurancebensaidv2.Login.<init>(Login.java:37)
  at assurancebensaidv2.Login$8.run(Login.java:761)
  at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
public class jdbcManager {

    public HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
    public static Connection conn;
    private Statement s;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public jdbcManager() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erreur Driver  ", "Etat de L'opération", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Logger.getLogger(jdbcManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //===================================================================
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.88:3306/agenceassurance", "root", "12345");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
          //  javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erreur Connection Base de donnée", "Etat de L'operation", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         }
    }}
```

Comment: Can you please exactly write the error you got?

Comment: try to ping this address `ping 192.168.1.88`

Comment: Are you running the java code on a different machine to the one running WAMPServer?

Comment: @Anubhav I have not got any error, I have only this exception of a timeout.

Comment: @YCF_L ping between two PCs it works fine

Comment: @RiggsFolly My idea is to run Java code (Application) on different machines (Windows) and they connect to a specific machine (Windows) that the database is installed

Comment: Then you need to create an account on MYSQL Server that is allowed to connect from a remote ip. By default and for obvious security reasons the `root` account is setup to only be allowed to connect to MySQL Server from the machine running MySQL Server. ___Dont change root to be allowed to connect remotely___ Create a new User account that is only allowed to see the single database you want to connect to

Comment: @RiggsFolly it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to connect to MySQL from a remote machine you need to create an account on MYSQL Server that is allowed to connect from a remote ip.

By default and for obvious security reasons the root account is setup to only be allowed to connect to MySQL Server from the machine running MySQL Server.

**Dont change root to be allowed to connect remotely** Create a new User account that is only allowed to see the single database you want to connect to

Comment: how can I accomplish that? would like to give me an example?

Comment: More than willing to, but how to acomplish what?

Comment: how to create an account on MYSQL Server that is allowed to connect from a remote IP.

Comment: Use phpMyAdmin from the PC running WAMPServer. See [the manual for User management](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html)